# Duplicate local variable error with Scanner object and while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

When passing in a Scanner object in java and using a while loop to access each line, an error says I have a duplicate local variable ("fileContents" in the very first line).

```
    static Map<String, Integer> countCategories(Scanner fileContents) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> categoryCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    while (fileContents.hasNext()) {
        String line = fileContents.nextLine();
        String[] lineItems = line.split(",");

        String category = lineItems[2]; // specified position in CSV file


        if (categoryCount.get(category) == null) {
            categoryCount.put(category, 1);
        } else {
            categoryCount.put(category, categoryCount.get(category) + 1);
        }
    }
```

To further expound on this, I'm just organizing information from a file, and I'm new to Java. Am I even doing this HashMap right, or should I be formatting this method and/or the hash map created inside in an entirely different way?

As requested, the rest of my main:

```
    public class PA2Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String fileName = args[0];
        Scanner fileContents = new Scanner(new File(fileName)); // temp var

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // recreate fileContents to use outside of try/catch
    String fileName = args[0];
    Scanner fileContents = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    HashMap<String, Integer> organizedCategories = countCategories(fileContents); // call function

    if (args.length > 1) {
        if (!"LOCATION".equals(args[1]) || !"CATCOUNT".equals(args[1])) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Command");
        } else {
            //process commands
            if (args[1].equals("CATCOUNT")) {

            }

            if (args[1].equals("LOCATION")) {
            // organize info in fi
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Formatting is a little weird, but I hope that makes sense. Obviously, I haven't done a lot with the rest of the program and this isn't very clean. The error message just states: Duplicate local variable fileContents

And a "quick fix" is renaming it.

Comment: Did you use the variable name fileContents anywhere else in your class?

Comment: Yeah, I have Scanner fileContents = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

in my main, but that's where I'm creating the variable, right?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the class and the exact error message you're getting

Comment: Please share the entire class..

Comment: Why are you creating 2 `Scanner`s? How is the second one not in a `try-catch` block when it throws checked exceptions? How are the first and second code snippets related?

Comment: That is the rest of my class, I just didn't post the code in the right order. I haven't written anything else since I'm stuck on just purely organizing this in a dictionary. The second one isn't in a `try-catch` block because I already tested it in the first one. Previous classes said not to put a whole bunch into the try-catch, so I just recreated the same thing outside of it to use later on.

Comment: if you copy this code into a "new class" there are no compilation errors (after commenting out "organizeContent") so I'm guessing organizeContent contains a line that goes something like "Scanner fileContents =  <whatever>"

Comment: But it won't compile if it's not in a `try-catch` block. What is the line `organizeContent` in the that block? It's illegal. How is the method `countCategories` related to the second block?

Comment: Sorry, I was renaming some methods and I didn't change it everywhere. I also moved it out of the try block to stay consistent with what I said earlier about keeping the try-catch small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have two variables with the same name in a class most of the time, and especially if the scope of them is the same like it is here with both in the same method. Even if the type of the object was different, the compiler would have no way to differentiate and pick which one you want to use so it won't compile.

In the code you provided, we can see that you used declared 2 Scanner objects with the same name which will cause the error every single time you try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String fileName = args[0];
***     Scanner fileContents = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String fileName = args[0];
*** Scanner fileContents = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    HashMap<String, Integer> organizedCategories = countCategories(fileContents); 
    if (args.length > 1) {
        if (!"LOCATION".equals(args[1]) || !"CATCOUNT".equals(args[1])) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Command");
        } else {
            if (args[1].equals("CATCOUNT")) {
            }
            if (args[1].equals("LOCATION")) {
            }
        }
    }
```

To fix this error generally, you could just rename one of the variables, but in your case, I don't think that having 2 Scanner objects is even necessary.

The try-catch clause should be used specifically for the lines of your code that have an actual possibility of throwing an exception, in this case initializing the scanner.

A cleaner way to write your code with this in mind would be

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String fileName = args[0];
    Scanner fileContents;
    try {
        fileContents = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HashMap<String, Integer> organizedCategories = countCategories(fileContents);
    if (args.length > 1) {
        if (!"LOCATION".equals(args[1]) || !"CATCOUNT".equals(args[1])) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Command");
        } else {
            if (args[1].equals("CATCOUNT")) {
            }
            if (args[1].equals("LOCATION")) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that right now it's all outside of the try statement, that's why I did it twice. Some of my professors have said before that it's bad style to put a bunch of things in the try block, so I tried putting it outside and just recreating the whole thing again since fileContents has limited scope. Is there any way to make the try-block statement small or should I just put everything into try?

Comment: Added more info to answer this question

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you!! I didn't realize I could declare the Scanner out there without setting it to anything like that!